# GIDSign in Delegate not getting called on real Device

Tags: ios, delegates

I integrated Google + SDK recent version and its working well in simulator but running on the real device delegate is not getting called.Please assist me for resolving this.This is the code i am using on simulator no issues but on real device the delegate methods are not getting called.

```
- (IBAction)googlePlusSinInW2R:(id)sender {
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] setUiDelegate:self];
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"931697643692-7ns75vnf7gai.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes = @[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"];
    userEmail.text=@"";
    confirmEmail.text=@"";
    userPassword.text=@"";
    confirmPassword.text=@"";
    userFirstname.text=@"";
    userLastname.text=@"";
    userGender.text=@"";
    dateofBirth.text=@"";
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
}
```

Comment: Please any one faced this issue and got solved let me have some ideas on this

Comment: Try setting delegate on viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad,
then on action method call other necessary stuff

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this:

> [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].allowsSignInWithWebView = YES;